# can't find youtube.js (Typescript, Angular2, YoutubeApi )

Tags: youtube-api, typescript, angular

I have a youtube.d.ts file from DefinitelyTyped project. It works great in my webstorm at edit time but when i go to run it I get a 404 typings/youtube.js not found. There is no file there. What do I do to get this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 404 typings/youtube.js

I believe you have something like `require('typings/youtube.js')` somwhere in your code.

**This should not be there**.

## Fix

Webstorm has magic inference to help you develop anyway you want. However your runtime might not support this.

- Remove the `require` call,
- don't confuse `typings` with *runtime dependencies*.
- Read up on modules (https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html) and commonjs / webpack (https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader)

Comment: I did have a import {YT} from 'typings/youtube and I removed it and I am past that error. I still have intellisense so I take it that just having a youtube .d.ts in the typings folder locate the type definitions, at least with webstorm.  Thank you for the references.